# how to implement application tests in xcode4?

Tags: iphone, testing, xcode4, xcode3to4

I'm trying to add some Tests for my application. Following the Document from Apple, I add two testing bundles to my project.
The logic tests are no problem, but when I try to make the application tests on a device I always get  the error that the logic tests don't run on a device.

In Xcode 3 there is no problem with that. Only Xcode 4 throws this error...

Any suggestions?

Thanks, Tim

Answer (score 34, accepted):

i was also having problems with setting up application tests in xcode4.
A solution that worked for me was as follows:

Assuming you have an application target called "MyApp"

1. Add a new target of type "other/Cocoa Unit Testing Bundle" to the project e.g "MyAppTesting". Here all Unit test files are located.
2. Go to MyAppTesting Build Phases and add MyApp as Target Dependency. This assures that MyApp is build before building the MyAppTesting target.
3. Open the Build Settings of MyAppTesting and change

   - Bundle Loader: $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/MyApp.app/MyApp
   - Test host: $(BUNDLE_LOADER)

   That causes the tests to run within MyApp.
4. Open the Build Settings of MyApp and change

   - Symbols Hidden by default: NO (for both)
   - Strip debug Symbols during Copy: Debug:NO

   By doing so you do not have to include every .m-file into the test target.

To run the test on a device plugin the device and select the scheme "MyAppTesting on device" and run as test. Assure that the mentioned scheme has set "Debug" within Test/Build Configuration which should be default.

Best regards.