# how to run application testing using Xcode 4 and OCUnit?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, ocunit

I am using OCUnit to write unit test, i tried GHUnit but it does not suit my case.

I do want to run a application test because my code heavily relied on my ApplicationDelegate instance. But i can only figure out how to run logic test but not application test.

This is a sample testing code from template, but either my test failed (no application delegate) or no testing code run at all.

```
- (void) testAppDelegate {

    id yourApplicationDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    STAssertNotNil(yourApplicationDelegate, @"UIApplication failed to find the AppDelegate");

}
```

I found a [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html) from apple about how to set up the test, but it is not for Xcode 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found answer here
[how to implement application tests in xcode4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637272/how-to-implement-application-tests-in-xcode4/6138044#6138044)

> Assuming you have an application target called "MyApp"
>
> 1. Add a new target of type "other/Cocoa Unit Testing Bundle" to the
>      project e.g "MyAppTesting". Here all Unit test files are located.
> 2. Go to MyAppTesting Build Phases and add MyApp as Target
>      Dependency. This assures that MyApp is build before building the
>      MyAppTesting target.
> 3. Open the Build Settings of MyAppTesting
>      and change
>
>    - Bundle Loader: $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/MyApp.app/MyApp
>    - Test host: $(BUNDLE_LOADER)
>
>    That causes the tests to run within MyApp.
> 4. Open the Build Settings of MyApp and change
>
>    - Symbols Hidden by default: NO (for both)
>    - Strip debug Symbols during Copy: Debug:NO
>
>    By doing so you do not have to include every .m-file into the test target.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.