# Many compile errors in Xcode 5 unit testing with GoogleMaps.framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, xcode5

I'm using the XCTest framework to unit test iOS my app.  The app includes the GoogleMaps.framework and I've been able to add the framework itself to the the testing target but I receive many compile errors that are incredibly cryptic.  I'm sure that I'm missing something simple but I have not yet been able to find the solution.  I have also followed many of the directions of many of other posts related to similar issues: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512792/libraries-not-found-when-using-cocoapods-with-ios-logic-tests), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637272/how-to-implement-application-tests-in-xcode4/6138044#6138044), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268259/xcode-4-unit-testing-linker-error) to name a few.  I believe, but am not positive, that there is an issue linking the framework's resources bundle to the testing target.

The error is this "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" or "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s" depending on whether I'm trying to run the test on the simulator or an actual device, respectively.

Here is what XCode gives me when I select Product > Test:

```
Ld /Users/fitzgeraldsimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuardlyTwo-    exkiohzzsvdhtddmpgulwtyrytvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GuardlyTwoTests.xctest/GuardlyTwoTests normal x86_64
cd /Users/fitzgeraldsimran/Documents/iOS/Guardly_2/guardly-iphone-2
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode51-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode51-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode51-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode51-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/fitzgeraldsimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuardlyTwo-exkiohzzsvdhtddmpgulwtyrytvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/fitzgeraldsimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuardlyTwo-exkiohzzsvdhtddmpgulwtyrytvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode51-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode51-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/fitzgeraldsimran/Documents/iOS/Guardly_2/guardly-iphone-2 -filelist /Users/fitzgeraldsimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuardlyTwo-exkiohzzsvdhtddmpgulwtyrytvy/Build/Intermediates/GuardlyTwo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GuardlyTwoTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GuardlyTwoTests.LinkFileList -bundle_loader /Users/fitzgeraldsimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuardlyTwo-exkiohzzsvdhtddmpgulwtyrytvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GuardlyTwo.app/GuardlyTwo -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -framework QuartzCore -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework GoogleMaps -framework XCTest -framework CoreData -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/fitzgeraldsimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuardlyTwo-exkiohzzsvdhtddmpgulwtyrytvy/Build/Intermediates/GuardlyTwo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GuardlyTwoTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GuardlyTwoTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/fitzgeraldsimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuardlyTwo-exkiohzzsvdhtddmpgulwtyrytvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GuardlyTwoTests.xctest/GuardlyTwoTests

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex", referenced from:
  _GMSCreateCGImageWithData in GoogleMaps(GMMImageSupport.o)
"_CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider", referenced from:
  _GMSCreateCGImageWithData in GoogleMaps(GMMImageSupport.o)
"_GLKMatrix3Identity", referenced from:
  gmscore::vector::GLLineGroup::SetTransform(gmscore::math::Matrix4f const&,    gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::vector::Camera> const&) in GoogleMaps(GLLineGroup.o)
  gmscore::vector::GLAlphaOnlyTextureShaderProgram::GLAlphaOnlyTextureShaderProgram(bool) in GoogleMaps(GLBasicShaderState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(unsigned int) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(unsigned int) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureUnit) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureState(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::ImageData> const&, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::TextureUnit, bool, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::Filter, gmscore::renderer::TextureState::Filter) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
  ...
"_GLKMatrix4Identity", referenced from:
  -[GMSGLVectorTile applyTransform:camera:] in GoogleMaps(GMSGLVectorTile.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::PointsBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in     GoogleMaps(GMSPointsEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::StickerBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSStickersEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::GLTileUpdaterBehavior::UpdateAndTransformTile(objc_object*) in GoogleMaps(GMSTilesEntityProvider.o)
  (anonymous namespace)::BubbleBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GMSBubbleEntityProvider.o)
  gmscore::streetview::Panorama::Panorama(int, int, int, int, int, int) in GoogleMaps(Panorama.o)
  gmscore::vector::UpdateMyLocationBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) in GoogleMaps(GLMyLocation.o)
  ...
"_GLKMatrix4Invert", referenced from:
  gmscore::streetview::Camera::Unproject(gmscore::math::Vector2f const&, bool*) const in GoogleMaps(Camera-B046EE312980DB98.o)
  gmscore::vector::Camera::UpdateInternals() in GoogleMaps(Camera-3E3856CABC8A9C74.o)
  gmscore::renderer::Camera3D::SetTransform(gmscore::math::Matrix4f const&) in GoogleMaps(Camera3D.o)
  gmscore::renderer::Camera3D::Transform() in GoogleMaps(Camera3D.o)
  non-virtual thunk to gmscore::renderer::Camera3D::Transform() in GoogleMaps(Camera3D.o)
"std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
  std::__1::enable_if<__is_forward_iterator<gmscore::model::ModelTriangle2D*>::value, void>::type std::__1::vector<gmscore::model::ModelTriangle2D, std::__1::allocator<gmscore::model::ModelTriangle2D> >::assign<gmscore::model::ModelTriangle2D*>(gmscore::model::ModelTriangle2D*, gmscore::model::ModelTriangle2D*) in GoogleMaps(GMSArea.o)
  std::__1::vector<gmscore::model::ModelTriangle2D,
```

And continues on for a very long time...

My unit test code is pretty straight forward, I'm just trying to get it to compile:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h> 
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

@interface MyAppTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation MyAppTests

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testGoogleMapsAPI
{
    XCTAssertEqual(YES, [[MyAppDelegate appDelegate] activateGoogleMapsAPI], @"Google API    should return YES");
}

@end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure all frameworks needed for running your tests actually are linked against the test target. Ow, and make sure you understand that unit-tests are not integration tests - they should focus on small units.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't included all the frameworks in the test target.  Although I am quite aware of the difference between unit tests and integration tests.